# RejectedExecutionException when using AWS TransferManager

Tags: java, exception, file-upload, amazon-s3

I have the following method to do multipart uploads to amazonS3:

```
public static void uploadToS3UserPath(String filePath, String bucket, String userPath) {
    ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();
    config.setProxyHost("host");
    config.setProxyPort(3128);
    config.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);

    TransferManager tm = new TransferManager(new AmazonS3Client(credentials, config));
    TransferManagerConfiguration conf = new TransferManagerConfiguration();
    conf.setMinimumUploadPartSize(50 * 1024 * 1024); //use 50 megabytes parts;
    tm.setConfiguration(conf);

    PutObjectRequest req = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, userPath, new File(filePath));
    req.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
    req.setStorageClass(StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy); //we do it to decrease storage costs
    Upload up = tm.upload(req);

    try {
        up.waitForCompletion();
        tm.shutdownNow();
        System.out.println("Upload completed successfully");
    } catch (AmazonClientException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Utilities.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
        tm.shutdownNow();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Utilities.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
    }
}
```

The thing is sometimes I'm getting:

```
    com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to complete transfer: null
            at
    com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.Transfer.unwrapExecutionException(Transfer.java:226)
            at
    com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.Transfer.rethrowExecutionException(Transfer.java:210)
            at
    com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.Transfer.waitForCompletion(Transfer.java:116)
            at
   xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.agent.Utilities.uploadToS3UserPath(Utilities.java:373)
            at
    xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.agent.AbstractAgent.uploadOutputToS3(AbstractAgent.java:312)
            at
    uk.org.infectogenomics.agent.AbstractAgent.uploadOutputToS3(AbstractAgent.java:305)
            at xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.hostEl.HostEl.run(HostEl.java:598)
            at xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.agent.Agent.main(Agent.java:98)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
            at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1759)
            at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:767)
            at
    java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:216)
            at
    java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:378)
            at
    com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.reschedule(UploadMonitor.java:210)
            at
    com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.upload(UploadMonitor.java:197)
            at
    com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:148)
            at
    com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:49)
            at
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
            at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
            at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

The thing is I have no idea why this manifests itself just for random uploads. Clearly the reason is the RejectedExecutionException? Could it be because I'm shuttingdown the TransferManager prematurely?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was going on?

Comment: Using the multi threaded implementation ultimately proved to be very hard to get right, irrespective of the fact that they have pretty good looking API's so instead I just reverted back to using the single-threaded version - with uploadrequest. Because I'm using ja.net we have pretty good connectivity to the cloud so it is not a biggie to  transfer a couple of gig files to amazon

Answer (score 0):

> Could it be because I'm shuttingdown the TransferManager prematurely?

That's indeed the trigger for this behavior, but the root cause had been a bug in the [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/), see Eric Milas similar question [Amazon AWS Java SDK TransferManager issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8609872/45773):

> TransferManager contains an UploadMonitor and UploadMonitor has a
>   static ScheduledExecutorService called timedThreadPoool.
>   TransferManager.shutdownNow() calls the static method
>   UploadMonitor.shutdownNow() which calls
>   timedThreadPoool.shutdownNow(). The next time any call to
>   UploadMonitor.reschedule() is made the RejectedExecutionException is
>   thrown.

[His own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8947097/45773) references the AWS Team response to [TransferManager Thread Issue](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/post!reply.jspa?messageID=306678) , which confirms this bug, and a respective fix has been implemented as of [Release 1.3.2](http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/Java/8448293683362259)):

> The [Amazon S3 TransferManager class](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html) was updated to address two bugs:
>
> Possible data corruption when uploading from an InputStream and
>   encountering IO errors during certain portions of the upload. Cleanly
>   shutting down timer threads when shutdownNow() is called on an
>   instance of TransferManager