# AWS Java TransferManager issue, JVM could not obtain any more native threads

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I've been fighting with a `TransferManager` issue for a few weeks now and I am hoping to get some feedback,

I have a server application that waits for tasks to be sent to it.  Some of these tasks require an upload to S3.  The task contains all of the upload information I need including the access keys.

In my actual upload code, I need to create a new `S3Client` and `TransferManager` object every time I need to do an upload because I do not know my access keys ahead of time.

After the system processes approximately 1200 uploads I received an error indicating that the JVM could not obtain any more native threads.  I attached a profiler to the application and noticed that the `TransferManager` object was not getting cleaned up properly, there were thousands of "s3-transfer-manager-worker-1" threads sitting idle.

I attempted to add a call to `TransferManager.shutdownNow()` after the upload was complete.  That did clean up the threads.  However, I started receiving a `RejectedExecutionException` whenever a new `TransferManager` was created and an upload was attempted.

`TransferManager` contains an `UploadMonitor` and `UploadMonitor` has a static `ScheduledExecutorService`.  `TransferManager.shutdownNow()` calls the static method `UploadMonitor.shutdownNow()` which calls `shutdownNow()` on the executor service.  This makes it so that I can no longer use any `TransferManager` objects, even if I try to create a new one.

How do I go about using multiple transfer objects without running out of threads?  This seems like it is a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was confirmed by Amazon as a bug.  See details here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=83520&tstart=0